# How to exclude specific identifier from IntelliJ IDEA search?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I have identifier `BadIdentifierName` used throughout bunch of project files. I do not ever want to match that identifier with my CTRL+SHIFT+F global search.

I am using case insensitive `ident` keyword as an input to the Search. This will match `ident` from these exemplary words: `GoodIdentifierName`, `ident`, `identation`, `myIdent`, `SOME_IDENTIFICATION`, **and...** `BadIdentifierName`.

I do not want to use regexes, because there are a lot of identifiers that I want to put on CTRL+SHIFT+F blocklist.

---

I do know we can exclude entire files or directories from search, yet that does not help me here.

How can I exclude specific identifiers?

Comment: There is no such feature in IntelliJ IDEA.